# How to search for a specific string in cell array

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I would like to search for a specific string in matlab cell. For example my cell contains a column of strings like this

```
variable(:,5) = {'10';'10;20';'20';'10;20';'10';'10';'20'};
```

I would like to search for all cells that have only `'10'` and delete them.

I tried using this statement for searching

```
is10 = ~cellfun(@ isempty , strfind (variable(:,5) , '10'));
```

But this returns all cells with `'10'` (including the ones with `'10;20'`).

I would like to have just the cells with pure `'10'` values

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not working as you expect because `strfind` allows for a *partial* string match. What you want is an *exact* match. You can do this using `strcmp`. Also, the input to `strcmp` can actually be a cell array of strings so you can use it the following way.

```
A = {'10';'10;20';'20';'10;20';'10';'10';'20'};
is10 = strcmp(A, '10');
%// 1  0  0  0  1  1  0
```

You could also use `ismember` to do the same thing.

```
is10 = ismember(A, '10');
%// 1  0  0  0  1  1  0
```

As a side note, most string functions (including `strfind`) can actually accept a cell array of strings as input. So in your initial post, the wrapping of `strfind` inside of `cellfun` is unnecessary.

Comment: To skip a step, you may go with `A(strcmp(A,'10')) = []`, in order to delete the unwanted cells immediately.

Comment: @JCKaz Technically that isn't skipping any steps, it's just performing the *next* step. If you really wanted to skip a step you could use `regexp` to return a cell array of the non-`'10'`s

Comment: Does `strfind` return logicals?

Comment: You're right @Suever. "Skipping a line" is more accurate.

Comment: @EyesOfÖzil You can google it and look at the documentation to answer that sort of question (the answer is [no](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html))

Comment: "The output of strfind indicates the starting index of each occurrence of pattern in str. If pattern is not found, then strfind returns an empty array, []. The strfind function executes a case-sensitive search."